# How to check dictionary contains certain value, not certain key?

Tags: dictionary, swift2

Fast way to check if dictionary contains certain value, like
"dictionary.contains(value)" in Java. Ex:

```
var dict:[Int:String?] = [1:"hello", 2:"world"]
```

How can I check if the dictionary contains "world"?

Comment: @Eric D Thank you for correcting my question in a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your only option is to iterate on each dictionary element to find if that value is present. There are multiple ways to do that, but they are all linear-time.

One such way would be:

```
foreach (key, value) in dict {
    if value == "world" {
        print("Found world")
    }
}
```

Another (shorter) way would be:

```
dict.values.contains("world")
```

Comment: Do you mind to show me an example that you think it is good? Just use the above example. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Tang, consider using `dict.values.contains("world")` instead of the foreach example.